# elasticsearch 'delete' API not working over ssh connection

Tags: ssh, elasticsearch

I'm having a problem with the Elasticsearch delete API. When I run a program that executes the following command:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/_all
```

from a remote host over ssh, I'm getting a gateway timeout error. I know that there's nothing wrong with my network. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's the response string I was getting. My program expected an output in JSON format, which lead to an exception being thrown.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Notification: Gateway Timeout</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  color: #2970A6;
}
a:link {
    color: #2970A6;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #2970A6;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
p.buttonlink {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.copyright {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 30px;

}
.details {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #969696;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 35px;
}

.shadow {
  border: 3px solid #9f9f9f;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  margin: 10px 35px 0px 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 600px;

  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
  /* For IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='cccccc')";
  /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='cccccc');
}
.logo {
  border: none;
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 30px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="logo"></div><p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="shadow">
<h1>This Page Cannot Be Displayed</h1>


<p>
The system cannot communicate with the external server (&nbsp;localhost&nbsp;).
The Internet server may be busy, may be permanently down, or may be
unreachable because of network problems.
</p>

<p>
Please check the spelling of the Internet address entered.
If it is correct, try this request later.
</p>



<p>
If you have questions, please contact
your organization's network administrator 
and provide the codes shown below.
</p>

</div>

<div class="details"><p>
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 23:52:12 GMT<br />
Username: <br />
Source IP: REDACTED<br />
URL: DELETE http://localhost/_all<br />
Category: <br />
Reason: UNKNOWN<br />
Notification: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include the error from your logs?

Comment: I added the response string I was getting.

Comment: Are you sure your ES cluster is up? What does `curl -XGET localhost:9200` yield?